# Can/Should rarely used columns be placed in a different table for performance?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sqlite

I have a table that contains data (blobs). Data is often read, rarely inserted, and never modified.

For all of this data, I compute hashes that I also store in the DB. These hashes are only checked when inserting new data, therefore, they are hardly used in normal, day-to-day routine.

My question is, is it worth the trouble to make a separate table for the hashes, is it reasonable to expect any performance gain for putting them aside? Or can I confidently just add an extra column to the table for the hashes, even though the hashes are rarely used?

*(Although I would be interested in a general answer, I must point out that I use MariaDB and sqlite).*

Comment: Youк "separate table for the hashes" will act by the same way as an index by this hash, but it needs additional support.Moreover, if DBMS supports the index by virtual calculated field this is the best solution. [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Secondary Indexes and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html).

Comment: Where exactly do you expect the performance gain to come from, considering that the entire table page is the minimum I/O unit?

Comment: @mustaccio Perhaps a table with less columns is faster to query? Esp. since a hash can be long, e.g. a SHA1 key is 40 ascii characters, SHA2 hashes are even longer.

Comment: "Perhaps"? Do you have any numbers that show that?

Comment: @mustaccio If I did, perhaps I wouldn't be asking this question?

Comment: My point exactly.

Comment: @mustaccio on the other hand, if you have proof of the opposite, don't hesitate to post an answer, I would be interested.

Comment: There isn't nearly enough details in your question for any definitive answer; this is why I asked about the reasoning behind your performance concerns. Consider posting the exact table definition, data statistics (number of rows, average lengths of values in various columns), and the SQL statements that you are most concerned about.

Comment: @Vérace what does the OS block size have to do with this?

Comment: @mustaccio - have deleted comment - just trying to reflect on the nature of the relationship between OS/File system block size and the database block size - will have to read more!

Answer (score 1):

(re: MySQL/MariaDB)  It depends.

- For small columns, say under 1KB, don't bother with the hash.
- For large columns, say over 7KB, it *may not* matter -- InnoDB puts large columns "off-record" in a block separate from the main part of the record.
- For medium-sized columns, say 1KB-7KB, the column is likely to be kept "on record", thereby making any action on the row fetch the bulky column, too.  This is even if you don't say `SELECT *`.
- Regardless of what you do, avoid using `SELECT *`; instead, spell out the columns you need.  (`*` will bite you if you ever add a column to the table.)
- Pack the hash into `BINARY(16)` for MD5, etc., rather than a `VARCHAR` of twice the size.
- The time taken to fetch a row is more than unpacking the columns.  That is, "how many columns" is not a metric to worry about.  (No, I don't have numbers to back that up; just decades of experience.)

The hash (whether md5, sha1, etc) is a bigger nuisance.  It is very 'random', thereby leading to cache misses when inserting a new hash or looking up by the hash.  This issue comes into play when the BTree with the hash is bigger than can be cached in the buffer_pool.  To phrase it another way, use of a hash on a billion-row table will slow down *all* accesses to the speed of the disk.  And it will slow down other processes due to cache misses.

InnoDB blocks are 16KB; the underlying OS or drive block size does not factor into *this* discussion.

In the opposite direction, consider putting frequently updated columns (clicks, Likes, views) in a separate table.  (But that's another Q&A.)